# Unused javascript on mobile performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, video.js

I am working on a website which uses video.js for background video. It works fine on desktop browsers.

On mobile browsers, it took a long time to load the website. I tried profiling through chrome devtools. It shows video.js taking some time to initiate itself.

I inititated the video player instance only on desktop browsers. Why would video.js took so much time to load itself on mobile browsers?

Thanks

Comment: What video-codec is used in your video file(s)?

Comment: And, I'm curious about the implications of your title 'unused javascript'.  So, maybe you could post the video.js-related  javascript code, as it appears on your webpage???